# Telerik RadGrid Row Index from user click

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Here is the code i'm using but the Item index is now the correct row index it jumps around so i think I have the wrong code.  Any help is welcomed!  Thanks

```
protected void FailureRadGrid_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "RowClick" && e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        FailureSourcePanel.Visible = true;
        EmployeeInputPanel.Visible = true;
        GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)FailureRadGrid.MasterTableView.Items[e.Item.];
        FailureDescriptTextBox.Text = item["FullDescrip"].Text;
        FailureCouponID.Text = item["CouponID"].Text;
        FailureProductTextBox.Text = item["Product"].Text;
        FailureUnitLabel.Text = item["Unit"].Text;
        FailureValueTextBox.Text = item["Value"].Text;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
var editedItem = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
FailureDescriptTextBox.Text =  editedItem["FullDescrip"].Text;
```